# Why can't we pass int array[] to hoo(int* &p)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, lvalue

In my understanding `array` in `int array[]={1,2,3,4,5}` is just a pointer to the first element of `array`. It means that `array` can be assigned to a pointer `ptr` of type `int*`.

Parameter `int* &p` in `hoo` will pass the argument by reference. It means we can change the passed argument to point to another value from within the `hoo`.

```
void hoo(int* &p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << p[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    // I can do this
    int* ptr = array;
    hoo(ptr, 5);

    // but not this.
    //hoo(array, 5);
}
```

## Question

Why can't we pass int `array` to `hoo` without `ptr` ?

Comment: *"Parameter `int* &p` in `hoo` will pass the argument by reference. It means we can change the passed argument to point to another value from within the `hoo`."* What if you tried to do `p=nullptr` in `hoo`? What would the intended result be for `array`?

Comment: An array is __not__ a pointer to its first element. Your title asks a entirely different question than your question-text. You _can_ pass a `int[]` to a `int*`, but not to a `int*&`.

Comment: @tkausl I edited the question title and it invalidates part of your comment.

Comment: An array is **not** a pointer, full stop.  It will save you many headaches if you treat an array as what it really is.  Yes, it can decay to a pointer in most cases but don't think of it as a pointer.  Additionally, you can just stop using raw arrays and use `std:array` in their place.  They'll make issues like this go away.

Comment: is there some real problem you are trying to solve or is this just for learning purpose? In either case, use an `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: @user463035818: learning c++ and opencv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In my understanding array in int array[]={1,2,3,4,5} is just a pointer to the first element of array.

This is not correct. Arrays are arrays and pointers are pointers. They are distinct types with distinct properties. They are often confused because an array has the property that it will eagerly decay to a pointer to its first element.

`hoo(array, 5);` tries to convert `array` to an `int*` but the result of that conversion is an rvalue and can't be bound to a non-`const` reference. If, for example, you changed `hoo` to take a `const` reference it will compile fine :

```
void hoo(int* const &p, int n) { }

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    hoo(array, 5);
}
```

In that case, you cannot change *what* `p` points to, making the use of a reference pointless.

Answer (score 3):

When a function takes an `int* &` parameter, that is, a (non-move) reference to a pointer-to-an-`int` - then there needs to be a bona fide pointer variable to which that reference is referring. It can't be a temporary pointer value. Thus you can't do:

```
int x;
hoo(&x, 123);
```

because there's no pointer variable to refer to - just the temporary. It's essentially the same thing with your `int[5]`. There isn't actually an `int*` variable anywhere - there are just 5 `int`s. When you pass `array` to `hoo()`, what C++ does with that identifier is an [array-to-pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying): It actually passes `&(array[0])`. So just like in the previous case, that won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers already explain the problem. I want to suggest a change of coding practice.

Use of `void hoo(int* &p, int n)` as function declaration is very very old style. Using templates, you can let the compiler deduce the size and get a reference to the array, which obviates the need for using a pointer.

```
template <size_t N>
void hoo( int (&p)[N]) // The argument is a reference to an array of N elements.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << p[i] << endl;
}
```

The call to the function becomes natural.

```
int array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
hoo(array);
```

If your function needs to be able to support dynamically allocated arrays as well, you can overload the function as follows.

```
void hoo(int* p, size_t N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << p[i] << endl;
}

template <size_t N>
void hoo( int (&p)[N]) // The argument is a reference to an array of N elements.
{
    hoo(p, N);
}
```

Comment: That will not accept dynamically allocated array so pretty much it has very limited use.

Comment: @Slava, true. Updated the answer.